# Infimum of the distance between a point and a set defines a metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a metric on a topological vector space $E$ defining the topology of $E$. Let $N$ be a closed vector subspace of $E$, and $\phi: E\to E/N$ the canonical mapping. Denote $\dot{x}:= x+N = \phi(x)$. Prove that $$d'(\dot{x},\dot{y}):=\inf_{\phi(x)=\dot{x}} d(x,\phi^{-1}(\dot{y}))$$ defines a metric on $E/N$.

My attempt:

- To show: $d'(\dot{x},\dot{y})=0\iff \dot{x}=\dot{y}\,\, (\iff x\in \phi^{-1}(\dot{y})).$ If $\dot{x}=\dot{y}$, then $d(x,\phi^{-1}(\dot{y}))=0,$ hence, $d'(\dot{x},\dot{y})=0$. Suppose now  $$0=d'(\dot{x},\dot{y})=\inf_{\phi(x)=\dot{x}}\left(\inf_{\phi(y)=\dot{y}} d(x,y)\right) =^{[?]} \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot{x},\phi(y)=\dot y}d(x,y) \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon>0:\exists x,y:\phi(x)=\dot x,\phi(y)=\dot y, d(x,y)<\varepsilon.$$ From here I'm stuck.
- symmetry: would follow from the symmetry of $d$ and if equality $[?]$ above is true.
- triangle inequality: $d'(\dot x,\dot y)\le d'(\dot x,\dot z)+d'(\dot z,\dot y)$? $$ \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot x}d(x,\phi^{-1}(\dot z))+\inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}d(z,\phi^{-1}(\dot y)) = \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot x} \left[ d(x,\phi^{-1}(\dot{z}))+\inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}d(z,\phi^{-1}(\dot y))\right] = \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot x} \left[ \inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}d(x,z)+\inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}d(z,\phi^{-1}(\dot y))\right] \ge \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot x} \left[ \inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}\left(d(x,z)+\inf_{\phi(y)=\dot y}d(z,y)\right)\right] = \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot x} \left[ \inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}\left(\inf_{\phi(y)=\dot y}(d(x,z)+d(z,y))\right)\right]\ge \inf_{\phi(x)=\dot x} \left[ \inf_{\phi(z)=\dot z}\left(\inf_{\phi(y)=\dot y}d(x,y)\right)\right] = d'(\dot x,\dot y),$$ using that there is no $z$-dependency left and equality $[?]$.

Questions:

- Does $[?]$ hold?
- How do I complete the first part?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your first question is affirmative. For the second question: It's strange that you have a topological structure on the space and a premise that $N$ is closed (presumably with respect to that topology?), and then you introduce a completely independent metric $d$. I don't see how the topological structure of the space enters into any of this. Are you sure there's not an additional premise that $d$ is compatible with the topology according to which $N$ is closed?

Comment: Yes, I was not sure where $d$ came from in this exercise, but indeed, $d$ is a metric on $E$ that defines the topology of $E$, and $N$ is then closed w.r.t. this topology. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is affirmative. The infimum is the greatest lower bound. The greatest lower bound of the greatest lower bounds of a family of subsets of $S$ is certainly a lower bound of the elements of $S$. It’s also the greatest such lower bound, for if there were a greater one, that would also be a lower bound for each of the subsets.

For the second question, given $x$ with $\phi(x)=\dot x$, for each $n\in\mathbb N$ choose $y_n$ with $\phi(y_n)=\dot y$ and $d(x,y_n)\lt\frac1n$. (I’m using countable choice there; I’m not sure whether that’s actually necessary.) The $y_n$ converge to $x$. Since $N$ is closed, so is $\dot y$. Since $y_n\in\dot y$ for all $n$, the limit $x$ is also in $\dot y$. (You seem to write this as $x\in\phi^{-1}(\dot y)$; I’m not sure what the point of this distinction between $\dot y$ and $\phi^{-1}(\dot y)$ is.) Thus $\dot x=\dot y$.

Comment: I use $x\in \phi^{-1}(\dot y)$ to denote that $x$ is projected onto $\dot y$. The distinction between $\dot y$ and $\phi^{-1}(\dot y)$ is primarily the spaces they live in: the former is contained in $E/N$, whereas the latter is a subset of $E$.

Comment: I have a question: why can we choose such $y_n's$? They seem to be linked to some given $x$ with $\phi(x)=\dot x$, but $d'(\dot x,\dot y)=0$ would imply $\forall n: \exists x_n,y_n\text{ with } \phi(x_n)=\dot x,\phi(y_n)=\dot y: d(x_n,y_n)<1/n$. Why can we build up your reasoning with a given $x$?